# How to show a message box in Odoo 13 website

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I need to show a warning popup button when the user presses the "Checkout" button (just an ok/dismiss button) [image]

I avoid using `raise Warning()` or `raise ValidationError()` since I want to remain on the existing page and simply show a pop-up warning.

Can you please share the simplest way to do this in Odoo 13?

Answer (score 2):

On click **proceed checkout** button called `jsonRpc` where call your `json controller` with that add your custom logic on the controller and return that and on the js check with your condition and raise your Dialog-Box Like this,On Js:

```
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
ajax.jsonRpc("/custom/url", 'call', {}).then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
        var dialog = new Dialog(this, {
            size: 'medium',
            $content: _t("<div style='font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;'>Error.</div>"),
            buttons: [{
                text: _t('Ok'),
                classes: "btn-primary",
                close: true
            }],
        }).open();
    } else {
        // odoo logic
   }
});
```

Thanks